Temporary Information is remaining between executions of a stored procedure
I have the following table:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AttendanceRecords]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SampleDate] [date] NULL,
    [Weekday] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Department] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Area] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [TotalTime] [int] NULL,
    [FirstInTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [LastOutTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [GrossTotalTime] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

and the following stored procedure in SQL Server 2019:
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetGeneralAttendanceData]
(
    @FirstName nvarchar(50) = null,
    @LastName nvarchar(50) = null,
    @StartDate datetime = null,
    @EndDate datetime = null,
    @Department nvarchar(50) = null,
    @PartialName nvarchar(50) = null
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #finalTable (FirstName NVARCHAR(50), LastName NVARCHAR(50));
    CREATE TABLE #secondaryTable (FirstName NVARCHAR(50), LastName NVARCHAR(50));
    
    SELECT *
    INTO #TimeCards
    FROM AttendanceRecords
    WHERE 1=1 
        AND (@FirstName is NULL or FirstName = @FirstName)
        AND (@LastName is NULL or LastName = @LastName)
        AND (@StartDate is NULL or SampleDate >= @StartDate)
        AND (@EndDate is NULL or SampleDate <= @EndDate)
        AND (@Department is NULL or Department = @Department)
        AND (@PartialName IS NULL OR FirstName LIKE '%' + @PartialName + '%' OR LastName LIKE '%' + @PartialName + '%')
    ORDER BY SampleDate;

    DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX) = null;
    DECLARE @colsWithoutWeekdays NVARCHAR(MAX) = null;
    DECLARE @colsAndTypes NVARCHAR(MAX) = null;
    DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = null;
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = null;
    
    SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(d.SampleDate)
                        FROM
                        (
                            SELECT convert(nvarchar(25), SampleDate,25) as SampleDate
                            FROM #TimeCards
                        ) d
                        GROUP BY SampleDate
                        ORDER BY SampleDate
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                    ,1,1,'');

    SELECT @colsAndTypes = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(d.SampleDate) + ' NVARCHAR(50)'
                        FROM
                        (
                            SELECT convert(nvarchar(25), SampleDate,25)+' - '+ [WeekDay] as SampleDate
                            FROM #TimeCards
                        ) d
                        GROUP BY SampleDate
                        ORDER BY SampleDate
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                    ,1,1,'');

    SET @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE #finalTable ADD ' + @colsAndTypes;
    EXECUTE(@SQL);

    SET @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE #secondaryTable ADD ' + @colsWithoutWeekdays;
    EXECUTE(@SQL);

    SET @query = 'SELECT FirstName, LastName, ' + @cols + '
                  FROM
                  (SELECT FirstName, LastName, SampleDate, TotalTime FROM #TimeCards) x
                  pivot
                  (sum(TotalTime) for SampleDate in (' + @cols + ')) p
                  order by LastName, FirstName';
    
    SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO #finalTable ' + @query;
    EXECUTE(@SQL);

    SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM #finalTable';
    EXECUTE(@SQL);

    SET @SQL = 'DROP TABLE #finalTable';
    EXECUTE(@SQL);
    SET @SQL = 'DROP TABLE #secondaryTable';
    EXECUTE(@SQL);
    SET @SQL = 'DROP TABLE #TimeCards';
    EXECUTE(@SQL);

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#finalTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #finalTable;
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#secondaryTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #secondaryTable;
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TimeCards') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TimeCards;
END

I've got to be missing something because it appears as though the data keeps staying resident between executions. I found that since I'm altering the temp tables using the Execute command (can you tell me what this is called, transaction?) so I had to do the same to drop the temp table. This took me a while to figure out because I thought all temp tables were stored in the same place. I really don't know where these are though, I searched and cannot find them.
My problem now is that when I search based upon @StartDate and @EndDate, the results will shrink, but will not expand after enlarging the gap between the two dates.
Plus, when I reduce the gap, I get the error:

Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 2
A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded.

But I just press F5 again and it executes correctly.
So, for example, I'll do the following:
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[GetGeneralAttendanceData]
        @StartDate = N'08/26/2024',
        @EndDate = N'09/29/2024'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO

This will work with no issue when ran just after the stored procedure has been altered.
Then I'll change @EndDate to 08/29/2024 and at first I get the error, then I'll run it a second time and it works correctly.
Finally, I will change the date back to 09/29/2024 and it will continue to return the results from the 08/29/2024 query. I've worked on this for a few hours now and I cannot find where I've gone wrong.
Please help and thank you in advance.

I can't repro: db<>fiddle

I'm guessing that your execute code becomes part of the procedure leading to interesting results. Add a GO before the executing code perhaps. Btw, there's no need to drop temp-tables at the end of execution of procedure, it's a sign of n00bish code

Well I like to drop my temp tables for clarify, but I wouldn't use dynamic SQL to do it. Nor would I then check whether they still exist statically and drop them again.

Aside... I believe all supported versions of SQL Server support string_agg now so you could expunge all of the stuff-for-xml tricks to improve code clarity and performance.

My understanding is that temp tables can actually be cached (at least structure and statistics). Brent Ozar has some stuff in his paid training for it, but an intro can be found at https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2020/11/paul-white-explains-temp-table-caching-3-ways/  (drill down to the three links from the headings for more info).

Nothing to do with the problem but dynamic sql is best executed with sp_executesql. This system procedure saves the query plan making it available for reuse. You should also parameterize the INTO #TimeCards query to avoid injection and encourage the reuse of the query plan.

Is there any chance that you've got bad data, such as inconsistent weekday names, that might be causing an error to be thrown in the dynamic SQL? If I seed the data with rows having the same date but different weekday names, I can trigger a Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition error. This did not reproduce your issue though.  Fiddle.

Thank you all for your suggestions.  I'll give a few of them a try and let you know if any leads to a solution.  As for the n00bish code comment,  you are half right.  My DB experience is with Oracle, Access 2000, and SQL 2000.  I have only recently been provided with an updated version of SQL.  I have a lot to learn when it comes to new features.  But, I did only start placing the DROPS when I had the undesired issues, thus why there are 2 sets of drops, and they actually helped.  IDK, but thank you for directing me toward better coding standards.

I don't know what your issue was with the temp tables, but they should drop automatically when you close the connection. Best practice would be to DROP IF EXISTS before you start.
But you don't actually need temp tables here. You can create dynamic SQL with the base query, then use that to first get the columns, then create the pivot. It will also be more efficient than using IS NULL OR conditions.
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetGeneralAttendanceData]
(
    @FirstName nvarchar(50) = null,
    @LastName nvarchar(50) = null,
    @StartDate datetime = null,
    @EndDate datetime = null,
    @Department nvarchar(50) = null,
    @PartialName nvarchar(50) = null
)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @baseQuery nvarchar(max) = '
    FROM AttendanceRecords ac
    WHERE 1=1
';

IF @FirstName IS NOT NULL
  SET @baseQuery += '
      AND FirstName = @FirstName';

IF @LastName IS NOT NULL
  SET @baseQuery += '
      AND LastName = @LastName';

IF @StartDate IS NOT NULL
  SET @baseQuery += '
      AND SampleDate >= @StartDate';

IF @EndDate IS NOT NULL
  SET @baseQuery += '
      AND SampleDate <= @EndDate';

IF @Department IS NOT NULL
  SET @baseQuery += '
      AND Department = @Department';

IF @PartialName IS NOT NULL
  SET @baseQuery += '
      AND (FirstName LIKE ''%'' + @PartialName + ''%'' OR LastName LIKE ''%'' + @PartialName + ''%''';

DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
SELECT @cols = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(d.SampleDate), '','') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SampleDate)
FROM
(
        SELECT convert(nvarchar(25), SampleDate,25) as SampleDate
        ' + @baseQuery + '
        GROUP BY SampleDate
) d;
';

PRINT @sql;  -- your friend

EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
  N'@cols nvarchar(max) OUT,
    @FirstName nvarchar(50),
    @LastName nvarchar(50),
    @StartDate datetime,
    @EndDate datetime,
    @Department nvarchar(50),
    @PartialName nvarchar(50)',
  @cols OUT,
  @FirstName,
  @LastName,
  @StartDate,
  @EndDate,
  @Department,
  @PartialName;

SET @sql = '
SELECT FirstName, LastName, ' + @cols + '
FROM (
    SELECT FirstName, LastName, TotalTime,
       convert(nvarchar(25), SampleDate,25) as SampleDate
    ' + @baseQuery + '
) x
pivot (
  sum(TotalTime) for SampleDate in (
    ' + @cols + '
  )
) p
order by LastName, FirstName;
';
    

PRINT @sql;  -- your friend

EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
  N'@FirstName nvarchar(50),
    @LastName nvarchar(50),
    @StartDate datetime,
    @EndDate datetime,
    @Department nvarchar(50),
    @PartialName nvarchar(50)',
  @FirstName,
  @LastName,
  @StartDate,
  @EndDate,
  @Department,
  @PartialName;

db<>fiddle
To be honest I would strongly recommend you use your application to do dynamic pivots, as SQL is not really designed for this.

Charlie, I'm using your comment about using my application for the dynamic pivots, and not SQL as a learning experience.  So, I'm not trying to argue, just understand why you say this.  I had been taught through my career that you set the database do all of the work of collecting and formatting the data because that's what it was designed to do.  Have things really changed that much that it's better to bring more data over the network and do the processing on the client machine?  Due to some of the old machines I had to develop for in the past, I had to worry about memory and network traffic.

Collecting data, yes. Formatting, absolutely not. It's not the place of a database to format data, it's up to the app how it wants to represent it. For example, date formatting, rounding, currency etc. Passing strings over the wire is also slower.

Good to know, thank you again.  The code you sent also worked for me.  I would rather accomplish this in C# anyways.  I haven't used MS SQL in years, and I guess it shows.

Note that the base query should still be dynamic as I've noted, it's only the pivot part that should be in the app level. If you use something like SyncFusion DataGrid etc then it can do the pivot directly in the grid.
